# Error when compile RMarkdown pdf file with package `vtable`

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, vtable, blogdown

I encounter errors when running the following simple code in RMarkdown.

````
---
title: "debugging"
author: ""
date: "11/12/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(vtable)
st(iris,out="kable")
```
````

I am using the latest version of `tinytex` and all R packages.

The error message looks like:

> ! Misplaced \noalign. \bottomrule ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global... l.168 \bottomrule
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile debug.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> debug.log for more info. Execution halted

or

> I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log
> manual.log. ! Misplaced \noalign. \addlinespace ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @ifnextchar [{@addspace }{@addsp... l.190 \addlinespace
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile manual.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> manual.log for more info. In addition:
> Warning messages:
> 1: package'vtable' was built under R version 3.6.2
> 2: package 'kableExtra' was built under R version 3.6.2  Execution halted

in my origin rmd file with similar code (different data frame).

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/339